# The page isn’t redirecting properly in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I am migrating my wordpress multisite (http://blogs.xxx.com) to a sub-directory in a new sever(http://blogs-test.xxx.com/blogs). After run wp-admin/install.php, I am having "The page isn't redirecting properly" error in all the pages. I have done these things:

- Checked the wp-config.php to make sure the siteurl and home are set
  same:http://blogs-test.xxx.com/blogs;
- Checked the .htaccess , and it is the same as the previous one;
- Deleted all the plugins in both wp-plugin and mu-plugins folder;
- Cleared all the cookies in broswer.

Am I missing something else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved the redirect loop by modifying the wp-config.php. It was about the sub directory for my site. I had to modify these two lines from

```
 define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'blogs.xxx.com/blogs' );
 define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
```

to:

```
 define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'blogs.xxx.com' );
 define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blogs' );
```

Not sure why, but this solved the redirect loop issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if nothing works and thank the guy in the link i give below as he has figured it out

```
First thing, make sure that at WordPress General settings, you have HTTPS version URL, not HTTP.

You can verify once by checking MySQL database table. If there is HTTP, you may change to HTTPS.

Or if you need very fast solution, simply define HTTPS version URL via wp-config.php

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain 
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
// so check for https existence
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; 

define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
 define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
 /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Then try to access, it should work. If it works, better, at last you can use Search/Replace to fix.

Also, one more thing. Make sure you don’t have vice-versa redirection in the .htaccess

#####Ref

    https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL
    https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL
```

This is the [reference link](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/page-isnt-redirecting-properly-errors-on-wp-admin/1515) to thank this guy!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the changes in the database as well?

> For a quick reference, this is a list of the main tables you will need to update with your new domain name:
>
> - wp_options > siteurl
> - wp_options >home
> - wp_site
> - wp_sitemeta > siteurl
> - wp_blogs > domain (change this for all instances that use your old domain)
> - wp_#_options > siteurl (the “#” refers to the blog ID of additional sites in your network)
> - wp_#_options > home
> - wp_#_options > fileupload_url

Read more here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/move-multisite-new-domain

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but no, it is not the database issue, and i just figured out it is about the path. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my new installation and I wasted lots of time trying everything but nothing worked..

I found the solution was rather very simple. In the set up of the multisite you are supposed to replace the htaccess contents with the newly generated content.

[image]

If your .htaccess still has the old content for the first site in the multisite the redirects for the secondary sites will never work for obvious reasons!!

**Solution is to replace completely the old htaccess content with the new one**!